Microsoft graph query for multiple items
I have a mailbox with a message that has x items like
 'sentDateTime': '2024-10-02T20:42:08Z',
 'singleValueExtendedProperties': [{'id': 'String '
                                          '{00020386-0000-0000-c000-000000000046} '
                                          'Name x-it-one',
                                    'value': '22ABCDEEC9F4E14F7ED2D5509958BA71BC097F0BAC63E8CAB122E636543EBB5C\r\n'
                                             'gtv8C6mPMNxF/UwSS/Uj+2E/jXm+EF1rXZ4g3fUd5+XX/pAXgd0GuRfeD0R9bmO2\r\n'
                                             'JV3cr1C9Bmbc3UtsCv'}],
 'subject': 'fooxyz',

My query can obtain 1, it produces the truncated result above.
url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/chupper@dgcloudqa.com/messages/\
AAMkAGJkMTlk...AADxNyKEAAA=?\
$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'String {00020386-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Name x-it-one')"


I want to query for all 10, so the resulting json has 10 items in the resulting singleValueExtendedProperties array.
How can I accomplish this?
And how can I delete them once I know I can access them?
